# Bukkit cannot get mob name that killed player

Tags: java, bukkit

Okay so I am trying to get the mob name if the player gets killed by a zombie (example) but I am always getting a NullPointerException on that.

I am sure I have messed up something in the code, but I really have a headache right now, and I can't find where is the problem.

Stack Trace: [image]

Here is the code:

```
package me.parat26.listeners;

import me.parat26.utils.SettingsManager;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;

public class PlayerDeathCauses implements Listener
{
    SettingsManager config = SettingsManager.getInstance();

    @EventHandler
    public void checkDeathCauses(EntityDeathEvent e)
    {
            Player p = (Player) e.getEntity();
            String victim = p.getDisplayName();

            EntityDamageEvent entityDamageCause = p.getLastDamageCause();
            DamageCause damage = entityDamageCause.getCause();

            String mob = e.getEntity().getType().getName();

            if (damage == DamageCause.DROWNING)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.drowned").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.ENTITY_ATTACK)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.mob").replace("<player>", victim).replace("<mob>", mob);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.ENTITY_EXPLOSION)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.mob-explosion").replace("<player>", victim).replace("<mob>", mob);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.FALL)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.fall").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.FALLING_BLOCK)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.falling-block").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.FIRE)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.fire").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.LAVA)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.lava").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.LIGHTNING)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.lightning").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.MAGIC)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.magic").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.POISON)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.poison").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.PROJECTILE)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.projectile").replace("<player>", victim).replace("<mob>", mob);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.STARVATION)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.starved").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.SUFFOCATION)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.suffocated").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.SUICIDE)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.suicide").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.VOID)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.void").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
            else if (damage == DamageCause.WITHER)
            {
                String death = config.parse("death.wither").replace("<player>", victim);
                ((PlayerDeathEvent) e).setDeathMessage(death);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pCHksYx.png

Comment: Player p = (Player) e.getEntity(); is throwing ClassCastException, what class can it be if it is not player? Also, the way you did the event handling wasn't really OOP, although I guess it WOULD have created a bunch of classes.

Comment: In future, please refrain from using images when you could paste the text in a code block. it makes it harder to help.

Comment: don't include images of text. copy and paste the text instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is where you are casting the `e.getEntity()` type to a `(Player)` type, and the Entity was not a player. You need to do a check to make sure the `e.getEntity()` is of the type `(Player)` before casting the `Entity` to a `Player`.

```
if(e.getEntity() instanceof Player){
Player p = (Player)e.getEntity();
}
```

Otherwise whenever a sheep or cow or something dies it will try to cast the `Cow` entity to the `Player` entity, which obviously wont work.

Also, I dont know if its actually the `Cow` type in bucket, that is just an example. Be sure to follow the API!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Based on this stack trace you are getting ClassCastException. This means you are trying to cast invalid class. You are trying to cast e.getEntity() to Player here

`Player p = (Player) e.getEntity();`

but instance returned by this call is not Player class, but CraftBat class. You can see what gets returned if you try

`System.out.println(e.getEntity.getClass());`

or try debugging in your IDE and see what class it is in Debug window. So this will work in this case:

`CraftBat craftBat = (CraftBat)e.getEntity();`

but it's most likely not what's you are looking for.